# How to make a space between "RahmanSajid" like "Mizanur Rahman Sajid"

Tags: java, user-input

```java
package com.exploreas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name1, name2, value;

        System.out.print("Enter Your First Name : ");
        name1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Your Second Name : ");
        name2 = input.nextLine();

        value = name1 + name2;
        System.out.println("Welcome! = "+value);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyuh2.png)

Comment: Do you understand what `name1 + name2` does. can you imagine slight change to that line you could try which might do what you want?

Comment: `System.out.printf("Welcome! = %s %s%n", name1, name2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value = name1 + " " + name2;` instead of `value = name1 + name2;`.

Comment: pleasw tick the answer for other people will know it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how + operator works. The + operator can be used between Strings to combine them. This is concatenation. Try to use:

```
String firstString = "Foo";
String secondString = "Bar";
System.out.println(firstString + " " + secondString);
```

This will yield

```
Foo Bar
```

Refer to [Java Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_strings.asp) in W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand what does `value = name1 + name2` means ?
It means, append/combine/concat to string and store it to `value`. So whatever you input, it will append/combine/concat. If you input space after first name, it will add a space after first name. If you don't, it won't. So, the solution is you need to add space manually like this

```
value = name1 + " " + name2;
```

And there are lots of methods available for concating string. I personally like `format` method on this case. Here is the example of using `format` method

```
value = String.format("%s %s", name1, name2);
```

But it will better if you `trim` your firstName and lastName before appending. `trim` removes the extra unwanted space from beginning of the string and at last of the string. So, here what i prefer

```
name1 = input.nextLine().trim();
name2 = input.nextLine().trim();
value = String.format("%s %s", name1, name2);
```

You can use `concat` method too. Search on google for more please.

Comment: Yeap that's what I'm looking for...Thank you so much brother

Comment: @Mizanur_Sajid i update the answer, please see that. And if you think it solves your problem please mark this as your answer and an upvote will be appreciateable.